# Could I disable syslog.service after installing rsyslog on Ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am making a minimal Ubuntu for embedded system starting from Ubuntu base. Our samba-related script code relies on rsyslog so I installed this package.

systemctl shows there is also a syslog.service, could I disable it? what is the relationship between syslog and rsyslog services?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I am stupid. They are the same one, just the rsyslog.service. syslog.service is actually a pointer to rsyslog.service.